# Did Sri Lokenath Brahmachari meet Sri Trailanga Swami at all?

Tags: saint, trailanga-swami

Some of Sri Lokenath Brahmachari's biographies claim that He met Sri Trailanga Swami.But Sri Lokenath Brahmachari refers to SrinTrailanga Swami as 'Hitalal Mishra' which is NOT the name of Sri Trailanga Swami as per ANY biography of Him that I read.

Can somebody throw light on this topic?

Comment: They met as per [this book](https://www.amazon.in/Incredible-Life-Himalayan-Yogi-Brahmachari-ebook/dp/B00KPRJ8PQ) and they even went to Sumeru mountain (place of Brahma on Bhuloka) which is at North Pole.  I can answer as per this book. Btw, he doesn't call Trilanga swami as Hitalala Mishra. Trailanga swami was from Andhra.

Comment: @TheDestroyer these books are written much later.The only authentic biography is by His disciple Brahmananda Bharati., who knwe Him very closely.There is no mention of Trailangaji in that book

Comment: Then we can't come to any conclusion. We can only know through books written by disciples.

Comment: @TheDestroyer We have to crosscheck diff biographies of both.Hitalal Mishra was not Trailanga Swamiji's name as per any of His biographies.

Comment: @TheDestroyer BTW Suddhanandaji was not a disciple of Baba Lokenath.

Comment: @TheDestroyer BTW n many books written in '50s and '60s, Lokenathji refers to Trailangaji as 'Hitalal Mishra'. I found that in the famous book 'Bharater Sadhak', the author expressed the view that most probably Lokenathji never met Trailangaji. Or it can be that He met some another monk named Trailanga Swami.